# Draw clean and smooth free hand drawing with CGContext (alpha + blend)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

Following is my code for free hand drawing using CGContext. I want to use the color having alpha value 0.6 and the blend mode as `kCGBlendModeColor`. But while drawing, I get the following effect : the color is overlapping and becomes dark. I want non overlapping and smooth draw.

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {

   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
 }

 -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint   currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self];

CGFloat brushSize = 35;

UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
CGFloat red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0, alpha = 0.0;

if ([color respondsToSelector:@selector(getRed:green:blue:alpha:)]) {
    [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
} else {
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    red = components[0];
    green = components[1];
    blue = components[2];
    alpha = components[3];
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushSize);

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, 0.6) ;
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColor);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];

 }
```

[image]

Comment: hi prerna,i just give one idea which i implemented in my code, i think you can store whole location point in array and after that when your drawrect method call just check there that the points are already exist in array or not.. if exist then skip the point otherwise add this point and draw line with your main point's array....

Comment: For that i will have to iterate through the saved points in the array after consistently drawing array will become very large and response will become very slow.

Comment: ok now just see some logic from this tutorial and also download demo if required http://www.bukisa.com/articles/231702_iphone-drawing-over-an-image-part-1

Comment: in above tutorial, DrawView class's pointArray is useful to draw line on view so any point is not overlap... :)

Comment: But when touches are ended and i draw another line when it overlaps with the other lines their intersection is dark colored.

Comment: yes i know and for this problem just use DrawView class that clear whole rect before drawing new line and after get whole array and draw all points on view..

Comment: when you touch on view at that time your class method drawRect is called at that time if first you clear whole view clear means remove all drawing from view and after that add line with your stored array like pointArray of DrawView class.. and just use the DrawView and try to understand the code of the Demo i am sure you got solution from this... :)

Comment: Yes i got the solution but that new touches part is difficult to understand

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17215/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-prerna-chavan)

Comment: Can you please help me with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to draw clean and smooth free hand drawing, use OpenGL, I have also used this and its really nice.

Follow this link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: But in GLPaint overlapping points are darken. And i want its literal opposite.

Comment: you can check for co-ordinates and compare, if there already exist pixel for that point, then you can reduce alpha..

Comment: How to do that or CGContext? Again i cannot store points in array and iterate every time. This will make it slow.

Comment: As you are working in OpenGL there are many functions in built available which you need to search....

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want to do, but one potential solution would be to draw with full alpha into an "extra" subview that you create that then has its alpha value set to .6.

In other words, draw with 1.0 alpha, but draw in a view with an alpha value of .6.

This should prevent a visible effect when you color on top of previous drawing while still retaining your desired alpha effect.

Good luck!  Hope that helps.

Comment: When alpha value is changed color becomes very faint, what if i want to use dark colors. I have already tried with the above code. That does not help.